# Android Emulator Fingerprint Authenticate Failing

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, appium-android

I'm trying to automate fingerprint authentication on local android emulator using Java and appium. I've set fingerprint option 1 on emulator and same has been passed through script. Finger print authentication failing and seeing the below error (Also error image attached here).

**Error**:
*Cannot recognize your finger print. Please try again*
[image: fingerprint auth fail]
Tried multiple options as below:

**Option1**: -> using io.appium.java_client.android.AuthenticatesByFinger
`((AuthenticatesByFinger) driver).fingerPrint(1);`

**Option2**: Using adb command

```
adb -e emu finger touch 1
```

**Option3**: Using telnet

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
finger touch 1
```

Above all options not working. Can any one please help me with your inputs to achieve this, is there any other way to automate fingerprint authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add new fingerprint in android security settings with command:

```
adb -e emu finger touch 1
```

(during fingerprint creation) then it will work

Comment: this worked after trying everything else :)